# Не получаю данные когда webBrowser1 Visible=false

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

В окне свойств webBrowser1 выбрал Visible=false и он перестал "грузить" данныне.
Появляется только диалоговое окно с "1". Если я ставлю Visible=true то все ок. Получаю "1" а потом "2"

```
public void OAuth()
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(String.Format(url));
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(isLoaded);
    MessageBox.Show("1");
}
public void isLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.DocumentTitle == "OAuth Blank")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("2");
    }

}
```

Вопрос: как можно скрыть webBrowser и он продолжал работать?

---

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OAuth(),
                                           TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
            public void OAuth()
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(isLoaded);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(String.Format("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=5211476&display=page&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends,photos,audio,status,groups,messages,email,notifications&response_type=code&v=5.42"));
        }
        public void isLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {         
            if (webBrowser1.DocumentTitle == "OAuth Blank")
            {
                string a = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                string[] b = a.Split('=');
                Token(b[1]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, загрузка может завершиться раньше, чем вы успеваете подписаться на событие завершения загрузки, поэтому сперва подпишитесь, а потом загружайте:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(isLoaded);
webBrowser1.Navigate(String.Format(url));
```

Во-вторых, `Visible` не оказывает никакого действия на загрузку (проверил на .NET 4.5, VS 2015). У вас в методе `isLoaded()` есть дополнительное условие -- может оно и не срабатывает? Уберите его и проверьте, или поставьте брейкпойнт на начало метода.

---

Исключение возникает из-за того, что вы вызываете метод веб-браузера в другом потоке:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OAuth(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

`WebBrowser` является просто оберткой для ActiveX-компонента, а у них все сложно с потоками: поток должен быть в STA апартаменте, при этом сам веб-браузер должен быть создан в том же потоке. Таким поток, например, является главный UI поток. Но если вы хотите работать с веб-браузером в другом потоке, придется делать примерно так:

```
private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
{
    var thread = new Thread(OAuth);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}

private void OAuth()
{
    var webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser1.Navigate(String.Format(url));
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(isLoaded);
}

private void isLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.DocumentTitle == "OAuth Blank")
    {
        // нельзя!
        //MessageBox.Show("2");
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что обработчик `isLoaded()` тоже будет запущен в другом потоке, и из него нельзя напрямую вызывать `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: Проблема с Navigate() когда Visible=false

"Исключение типа "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" возникло в System.Windows.Forms.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя

Дополнительные сведения: Невозможно получить дескриптор окна для элемента управления 'WebBrowser'. Элементы управления ActiveX, не базирующиеся на окнах, не поддерживаются."

Comment: @LittleFox так у вас еще и исключение. Показывайте весь код (добавьте в вопрос). При нормальном использовании такого исключения быть не должно.

Comment: @LittleFox обновил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! И вообще, спасибо людям которые не ленятся учить других :)

Comment: @LittleFox не за что!